# I am trying to find Vc(t) for t ≥ 0

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: H]

I am trying to figure out how to find \$V_c(t)\$ for \$t \geq 0\$ in this.

Comment: First you need to work out the current in the inductor and voltage across the capacitor for t=0. Have you calculated it ? If so, please [edit] it into the question.

Comment: *for t geq 0* - what does that mean?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Andyaka `geq` is ≥ - I edited the title accordingly.

Comment: You could try to find the Vc/Vin transfer function

Comment: You need to show us the work that you have done so far. This looks like a homework problem, and we don't hand out solutions to homework questions here.